# Ajax call not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to test AJAX in CodeIgniter, with no luck so far. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

Here is my `test_page.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/libs/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/libs/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/libs/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<button id="btn" onclick="gethtml()">ajax Test</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function gethtml(){
    var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajax_test";
    alert(""+url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert("ajax success");
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my function in controller:

```
public function ajax_test() {
    echo "return from ajax";
}
```

Comment: 1. Do you get any alerts? 2. Why are you loading jquery 3 times?

Comment: I found the problem. Actually ajax error event was getting fired because I didn't json_encode the response. Rest everything is correct.

Comment: can you try by replacing this line: `var url = "<?php echo base_url().'home/ajax_test' ;?>";`

Comment: @shubhamrs That is good but what did you do to fix it?

Comment: And you also removed those 2 extra jquery src script calls right?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I just added  echo json_encode("response from ajax");  in the ajax_test();      This solved the problem.

Comment: <button id="btn" onclick="return gethtml()">ajax Test</button> try this

Answer (score 1):

This Type of AJAX Call dataType is not required

Remove

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Use like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gethtml(){
    var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajax_test";
    alert(""+url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            alert("ajax success");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned solution.

```
<button id="btn">ajax Test</button>


$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#btn').Click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var url = "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajax_test";           
      alert(""+url);             
      $.ajax({           
            url: url,            
            type: 'POST',               
            dataType: 'json',            
            success: function(data){            
                   alert("ajax success");           
             }      
        });
    });
});
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Error in the above code is the response from the ajax_test() is not encoded into json. So, the error event of json is triggered and the code inside success is not executed. 
Always make sure to send json encoded data if you are specifying dataType as json.

Comment: And also READ your code and remove any redundant (silly) statements ie. Loading jquery 3 times... as you have done in the head of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try on view

```
<button id="btn">ajax Test</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#btn').on('click', function(e) {

    // e.preventDefault(); Not sure if you need it.

    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url('home/ajax_test');?>",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        // data: {
        // someinput: $('#someinput').val()
        //},
        success: function(data){
            alert(data['test']);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

On controller you can use the output class also.

```
public function ajax_test() {

    $json['test'] =  "return from ajax";

    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($json));
}
```